# How can I setup a python CLI application so that I can use it without directly referring to the interpreter?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse, setuptools

I want to build an application, say it's called helloworld, with a command line interface in python. My application as multiple nested modules and a top level module main.py.

Say the layout is :

```
helloworld/
   helloworld/
      __init__.py
      module1/
      module2/
      module3/
   setup.py
   main.py
```

At this point, once my project is installed I can run it using
`#> python path/to/helloworld/main.py arg1 arg2 arg3`

I want to be able to interact with the program using commands such as :
`#> helloworld arg1 arg2 arg3`, in a similar manner as for example, the Flask framework comes with a command line application I can use with `#> flask run`.

I looked around and found questions suggesting using a shebang. As far as I can tell, this is **not** what I want.

I want a self contained application I can install using pip and then launch directly without any reference to the python interpreter.

How should I go about this ?

**EDIT**

It is an important requirement to me that the package can be installed using pip and the command line interface is immediately available. Shebangs/fiddling manually with the path/creating an additional shell script do not solve my problem.

Comment: You can make a simple shell script.

Comment: This would be almost like adding a shebang. I really want the installation to be automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add main.py to your PATH. What happens when you are running `flask run` is that your teminal looks up the command flask in PATH and runs the program that it is pointing to. You could see it as a kind of shortcut to the program Flask.

By adding your program to your PATH, you can tell the computer that if you type `helloworld` in your terminal, the terminal should run `/my/path/to/helloworld.py`.

I don't know what OS you are on, so here are links for most common OS on how to add a PATH variable.

[Windows](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

[Linux](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-directory-to-path-in-linux/)

[Mac OSX](https://www.architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/)

Edit: After you gave more explanation, `setuptools` is what you are looking for. Please look at [this](https://gehrcke.de/2014/02/distributing-a-python-command-line-application/) reference to see how to use it.

Comment: Thanks ! I am aware of this process. However, it is very important to me that this configuration step is performed automatically when I install the project. I don't want users down the line to have to fiddle with their paths.

Comment: You should use setuptools then. take a look at this resource: https://gehrcke.de/2014/02/distributing-a-python-command-line-application/

Answer (score 1):

There's an explanation [here](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-scripts-keyword-argument) of how to tell setuptools to add a script to the Python Scripts-folder during the pip installation. You can then make that script be for example a bat-file that calls your Python-script. In that way you achieve both that you do not need to write `.py` for your script to run, and that it happens automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has already been answered, but just in case someone comes across this in the future..

Here's what worked for a new package I'm developing after reading up on this from many different sources.

tldr; use `setuptools` and add your command as a `console_scripts` option under `[options.entry_points]` in `setup.cfg`.

You will also need some other fields in `setup.cfg` or `setup.py` for package discovery to work. Check out the setuptools docs for that.

Example entry point:

```
[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
    mycmd = mypackage.mymodule:myfunc
```

For local development, you can install the package in editable (development) mode with `pip install -e .` which will allow you to test the command as if you `pip intall`ed it.

Alternatively, you could create a `__main__.py` that initializes your module when you run `python -m mypackage` from the root.

```
from mypackage import app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.main()
```

I personally opted for both. Usually your `main.py` (or `app.py` in my example) belongs in your package not project level dir. Then you would create `__main__.py` there as well.